# Why is Xcode "expecting an identifier" here?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios6

```
destination.wordsPerMinute = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)[self.wpmSlider.value]];
```

I'm accessing the view controller I'm segueing to's wordsPerMinute property (an NSNumber) and setting it equal to an NSNumber converted from an int, which was a float cast as an int.

Comment: You can use the new boxing syntax as well: `@((int)self.wpmSlider.value)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the brackets around `[self.wpmSlider.value]`.

Or use

`[self.wpmSlider value]`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [] brackets around `self.wpmSlider.value`

The compiler expects a method name as identifier here (like **numberWIthInt:** in the outer method call)

Answer (score 1):

You can use (in new compilers)

```
destination.wordsPerMinute = @(self.wpmSlider.value);// [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)[self.wpmSlider.value]];
```

If you want to convert it into integer value then :

```
destination.wordsPerMinute = @((int)self.wpmSlider.value);
```

Comment: It would be more like @(self.wpmSlider.value)

Comment: @redent84: thanks for pointing my mistake, copied from question and forgot to remove those [ ] :(

Answer (score 1):

With new compilers (XCode 4.5+):

```
destination.wordsPerMinute = @((int)self.wpmSlider.value);
```

Otherwise:

```
destination.wordsPerMinute = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.wpmSlider.value];
```